# AWK help to cut some value

Tags: linux, awk

In a variable the value can be like:

```
ab_5.6.533.162665_84.kn or ab_5.6.550_prod342.6.165834_84.kn
```

The value 162665 can be changing. The pattern will remain the same : ab_5.6.533.162665_84.kn or ab_5.6.550_prod342.6.165834_84.kn.. in any case I only want last 3rd last value.. like in this case 162665 . So the question is to grab the value in between ab_5.6.533./ab_5.6.550_prod342.6. and _84.kn which is 162665 here

I always want to grab(3rd last) "165834" this value.. any help will be appreciated

In short I need one command that works in both the cases.

I worked with cut, however it works for one case not for other

```
root:~# cat abc.log  | cut -d '.' -f 4
162665_84
6
root:~# 

cat abc.log 
ab_5.6.533.162665_84.kn
ab_5.6.550_prod342.6.165834_84.kn
```

Comment: What're you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO Raman, your question is NOT clear, which 3rd value you want to grab?

Comment: Indeed, 165834 seems to be either the 6th value, or the first portion of the 5th value.  If you split on underscore, it is the 3rd portion of the 3rd field (if that field is split on `.`), but...the question is horribly vague.

Comment: "Third last" when split by what? `_` and `.`... are there other characters that may be involved in splitting? Is the `or` part of the line or is this example two lines? If it's just `_` and `.` you can use: `awk -F[_.] '{print $(NF-2)}'`

Comment: @Raman, Raman comments are NOT meant for explaining the requirements, please edit your question with complete details and use CODE TAGS for your samples too.

Comment: You state that you want the 3rd. last value.  Please provide the exact specifications for what separates one value from the next.  That will make your question much clearer, and allow us to help you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$s"
ab_5.6.533.162665_84.kn
ab_5.6.550_prod342.6.165834_84.kn
```

If the field of interest is the 2 from last, you can do:

```
$ echo "$s" | awk -F "[._]" '{print $(NF-2)}'
162665
165834
```

Or, you could use `sed` if it is the field that is `.[0-9]+_`:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -nE 's/.*[.]([0-9][0-9]*)_.*$/\1/p'
162665
165834
```

Or you can use `rev` so you can use `cut` to get fields counted backwards:

```
$ echo "$s" | rev | cut -d _ -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1 | rev
162665
165834
```

But I have to admit what you are after is not exactly clear.

Comment: Thank you everyone, it helped

Comment: If this is helpful to you, please consider accepting the answer